# Ant: Using a fileset with the javac task

Tags: ant

I want to use a FileSet to indicate exactly which files I want compiled with the Javac task. I don't want any implicit behavior. My attempts at this have failed however. Here's what I've got so far:

A FileSet that contains all my source files.

```
<fileset id="srcfiles" dir="${srcdir}">
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
</fileset>
```

And a target that tries to pass it to javac.

```
<target name="build">
    <javac srcdir=".">
        <fileset refid="srcfiles"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

This gives me this error: `javac doesn't support the nested "fileset" element.`

After reading the Ant docs, I tried changing the inner most tag from `fileset` to `sourcepath`. This worked in the sense that the files were compiled, but it still errored out: `srcfiles doesn't denote a path`. I think the source was only compiled due to implicit rules.

How can I tell javac explicitly which individual files I want compiled? Or is this simply not how Ant is supposed to work? I come from a C++ background where identifying source files is a significant part of the build process. However, given Java's file naming and directory structure requirements, perhaps the implicit `**/*.java` pattern rule covers all use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ant manual for javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) says :

> If you wish to compile only files explicitly specified and disable
>   javac's default searching mechanism then you can unset the sourcepath
>   attribute:

```
<javac sourcepath="" srcdir="${src}"
       destdir="${build}" >
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
    <exclude name="**/Example.java"/>
</javac>
```

I don't think it's a good idea, though. In a well-designed project, all the files in a given directory (or in a set of directories) should be compiled. The files which shouldn't be compiled shouldn't be there at all, or should be in a separate directory.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want ? Compile all *.java code from single directory ? Or just compile one file ?

If you want to compile your all java source code ? Then you must define where your source code file located, and then you must define where your build directory located. This build directory is for *.class file after you compile your java code.

The easy way is, first you must create one file which is **build.properties** At this file, you can define where your source code directory, where your build dir, etc. This is simple example of **build.properties** file

```
# Source Code Properties ---------------------------
project.dir=.
src.dir=${folder.project}/src
dist.dir=${folder.project}/dist
build.dir=${folder.project}/build
test.dir=${folder.project}/testing
```

And then, in your **build.xml** file you can compile your java code like this :

```
<!-- define build.properties file -->
<property file="build.properties" />

<target name="compile" description="Compile all java code from src dir">
    <javac  srcdir="${src.dir}" 
            destdir="${build.dir}" 
     />
</target>
```

With this ant task, you can compile all your java code in **src** directory to **build** directory.

Comment: Currently, yes, I am just compiling all *.java files under a certain directory. I want a general solution just in case that ever changes. However, the more I think about it, I'm not sure that would ever change on a Java project...

Comment: Ussually on java project, first is you must consider about directory structure of your project. The 'standart' way is you must have **build and src** dir. Other directory is optional :) The easy way is, look at from maven directory structure :)

Comment: Look at this page  if you want to know more about java directory structure [Introduction to The Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thinking in C/C++ terms is futile in that case. In C/C++ you have usually a Makefile where you list all your files to compile and each `*.c` or `*.cc` file is -from the viewpoint of the compiler - independent of each other.

Quite the opposite is true for Java: If *would* give only one file to the Java compiler and this class references something *else*, then the compiler wants to see that 'else' in binary form. The compiler will try three things:

- Is that 'else' in some library in the classpath - if so that thing is used because it has been compiled already
- Is that 'else' in the destination path of the compiler - it might have been compiled already from source so simply take it
- Is that 'else' something where a source file can be found in the compiler's sourcepath - if so, then compile that first and then go back to the real task.

This is a little bit simplified but shows already most of the points where C/C++ is just to different:

- Sourcefiles are **not** independent of each other.
- The compiler might want compile more things than you can guess as a novice.
- Much of that automagic stuff works only because/if the compiler can guess a mapping between `.class` files and `.java` files.
- In Java there are not many arguments for the compiler. And all these settings apply to each source file. In C/C++ on the other hand you can have several kilobytes of `define` arguments, optimization settings and so on - perhaps different for each source file.
- A Java developer  doesn't want to micromanage a Java compiler - he wants to compile all files in a source directory.
- A Java developer doesn't want to work out the exact and formal dependencies between source files - a machine is better at a task like that.

This all boils down to the way Ant and Maven and any decent build system in Java works: Compile complete source directories. So yes, that's the way Ant want to work.