# ANT: ignore certain files from javac's sources

Tags: java, ant, generated-code

Currently, we define a path with

```
<path id="sources.production">
  <pathelement path="src/module1"/>
  <pathelement path="src/module2"/>
  ...
</path>
```

and then compile using

```
<javac ...>
   <src refid="sources.production"/>
   <classpath refid="classpath.production">
</javac>
```

Now we create some modified `.java` files (original files in `src/module2`) before this `<javac>` call and have put them before the other sources:

```
<path id="sources.production">
  <pathelement path="generated-sources"/>
  <pathelement path="src/module1"/>
  <pathelement path="src/module2"/>
  ...
</path>
```

Unfortunately, the compile fails now because the original and the modified `.java` files are both fed to the javac task. How to exclude the original source files easily from the javac's sources without large charges?

Answer (score 1):

you need an intermediate step which you copy all your source files to a new location and override them with generated ones, then use this new location as source folder for `javac`.

it may look something like this:

```
<path id="sources.4compile" location="all-sources" />

<target name="prepare-4compile">

    <!-- clean -->
    <delete dir="all-sources"/>
    <mkdir dir="all-sources"/>

    <copy todir="all-sources">
        <fileset dir="src/module1"/>
        <fileset dir="src/module2"/>
        <fileset dir="generated-sources"/>
    </copy>

</target>

<target name="compile" depends="prepare-4compile">
    <javac ...>
       <src refid="sources.4compile" /> 
       <classpath refid="classpath.production" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

other way, you may specify a fileset to `javac` disabling javac's default searching mechanism as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779078/ant-using-a-fileset-with-the-javac-task).